# How to delete a form from a cell in a Google Colab notebook?

Tags: google-colaboratory, user-experience

I might be going crazy, but I believe I read all the existing documentation on Google Colab and I couldn't figure this one out. Maybe it's not possible, but I find this to be very weird.

I am aware that the form can be hidden, and that I can simply copy paste the contents of the cell and just paste it in a new cell that doesn't have a form, but these are hacks and not how a regular user would try to do it.

I am wondering if I'm going crazy and I just can't see the delete form button, or did someone at google colab UX simply forgot about the delete form menu? (or maybe they chose to not add it for a reason I can't understand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the form with `#@param`. Forms are simply interpretable Python comments.

For example

```
i = 0 #@param {type:'slider', max: 10}
```

To remove the form, just remove all `#@param`, including the initial `#@title`

```
i = 0
```

The "Add a form" menu simply inserts the `#@title` parameter. There is no menu to remove this line.

Comment: all of it, I just don't want the form anymore, but after a refreshing sleep, I realized that the "Add a form button" is just an "insert code snippet" menu for ```#@title ```, so I can just delete what that comment. I now have a better understanding that forms are just a language written in the comments of python. From a UX point of view, I just expected that if a button exists that says "Add a form", there must also be a button that says remove a form, preferably in the same place.